# plot with Pandas, xticks

Tags: python, plot, pandas

I have some pandas DataFrame with the next structure:

```
  A B C
0 1 1 1
1 1 2 2
2 1 3 3
. . . .
```

Now, after sort operation, I want to plot for example column B. I use next command in pandas:

```
df['B'].head(10).plot(kind='bar')
```

Everything is fine, but pandas use for the x-axis the values from the first *unnamed* column. I want just to use the values from column C to *rename* the values in x-axis. At the first I try to use `xticks=df['C']` or just `x=df['C']`, but didn't get good results... I'm very sorry, but at the moment I can not post my plot, because I don't have enough reputation....

Answer (score 4):

`plot()` passes over all (additional) parameter you give to it to the original `plt.plot()`.

**Removed**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1],[1, 2, 2], [1, 3, 3]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df['B'].plot(kind='bar')
```

These commands return exactly what I expected. The values of 'B' are the bars, and the x-values are the indices of the DataFrame. After looking it up in the manual, I found that what I wrongly advertised as `left` is actually the data. In order to label it, you have to do the following (or similar):

```
ax = df['B'].plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_xticklabels(list(df['C']))
```

Comment: This works. And it seems that the list conversion is not needed in list(df['C']), just adding ax.set_xticklabels(df['C']) is enough