# Xticks by pandas plot, rename with the string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have this `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [2, 3, 5], 'C': ['name 1', 'name 2', 'name 3']})
```

```
   A  B       C
0  1  2  name 1
1  2  3  name 2
2  3  5  name 3
```

What is it the correct way to plot column `A` and use column `C` as xticks?

These do not work:

```py
df['A'].plot(xticks='C')
df['A'].plot(xticks=df['C'])
```

This changes the xticks but not the labels:

```py
df['A'].plot(xticks=[1,2,3])
```

Should I really convert to sequence? I have also some modification of the question. I got next Error message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: name 3
```

In short, I have a column of strings and want to use it as xticks for my plot.

PS: It doesn't look like there's a direct pandas plot function. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945971/pandas-timeseries-plot-setting-x-axis-major-and-minor-ticks-and-labels).

Answer (score 101):

The link you provided is a good resource, but shows the whole thing being done in `matplotlib.pyplot` and uses `.subplots()` to get to the axes. While I've done this before, I keep searching for ways to just use the built-into-pandas `.plot()` function as much as possible. To me it can simplify the code and makes it easier to leverage DataFrame goodness.

There do seem to be a number of things that aren't easy to do fully inside the parameters of `df.plot()` by itself, though. Luckily it returns an `matplotlib.AxesSubplot`, which opens up a much larger range of possibilities.

I copied your data above into a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(quotechar="'")
```

It looks sort-of like:

```
   A B  C
0  1 2 'name 1'
1  2 3 'name 2'
2  3 5 'name 3'
```

But, of course, much better in non table-crippled html. (Maybe SO will fix this one day).

Then all I had to do was:

```
ax = df.A.plot(xticks=df.index, rot=90)
ax.set_xticklabels(df.C)
```

If you are using IPython/Jupyter and `%matplotlib inline` then both of those need to be in the same cell. I had forgotten that at first and spent quite a bit of time trying to figure what was going wrong.

[image]

You can do it all using the `ax` variable:

```
 ax = df.A.plot()
 ax.set_xticks(df.index)
 ax.set_xticklabels(df.C, rotation=90)
```

but, as I mentioned, I haven't found a way to the `xticklabels` inside the `df.plot()` function parameters, which would make it possible to do this all in a single line.

The extra step to rotate the xtick labels may be extraneous in this example, but came in handy in the one I was working on when looking for this answer.

And, of course, you can plot both A and B columns together even easier:

```
 ax = df.plot()
 ax.set_xticks(df.index)
 ax.set_xticklabels(df.C, rotation=90)
```

[image]

Comment: Although it looks like you may have already gotten this answer when you asked almost the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472877/plot-with-pandas-xticks?rq=1).

Comment: It seems Pandas still not offer to relabel ticks, and your solution accessing matplotlib Axes is still valid in 2021. It is a bit strange to me, as specifying text labels for ticks seems a very common need.

Comment: @mins It’s way too late but fyi, if the labels are dataframe column values, then it’s possible to set tick labels in a single `plot` call. I added [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75551827/19123103) that shows it.

Answer (score 6):

#### As of matplotlib 3.5.0

Use [`ax.set_xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) with the new `labels` param to set ticks and labels simultaneously:

```
ax = df.plot(y='A')
ax.set_xticks(ticks=df.index, labels=df.C)
#                             ^^^^^^
```

Or, since [`df.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) returns an `Axes` object, we can chain it:

```
df.plot(y='A').set_xticks(df.index, df.C)
```

Note that [`plt.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) always had a `labels` param, so this change just unifies the `Axes` and `pyplot` APIs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you call `plot()`, you can pass column names as axis values to use its values as tick labels. So for the question in the OP, the following works.

```py
df.plot(y='A', x='C', legend=False);
```

or you can set column C as index and just call `plot` on column A:

```py
df.set_index('C')['A'].plot();
```

[image: res1]

You can also plot multiple column values in one plot by passing a list of column names:

```py
df.plot(y=['A', 'B'], x='C');
```

[image: res2]