# Matplotlib bar chart: how to change names on axis x

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, bar-chart, kaggle

I want to create a bar chart that will contain bars for 2 columns of dataframe.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

s = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
p_s = [0.05, 0.15, 0.20, 0.30, 0.20, 0.10]
p_s_x = [0.06005163309361129, 0.4378503494734475,0.3489460783665687,0.1404287057633398,0.012362455732360653,0.00036077757067209113]

df_to_plot = pd.DataFrame(data={"P(S)": p_s,
                                "P(S|X)": p_s_x,
                                "S": s})

df_to_plot.plot.bar(y=['P(S)', 'P(S|X)'],
                    alpha=0.7,
                    color=['red', 'green'],
                    figsize=(8,5))
```

This dataframe is here.

[image].

And bar chart I generate by

```
df_to_plot.plot.bar(y=['P(S)', 'P(S|X)'],
                   alpha=0.7,
                   color=['red', 'green'],
                   figsize=(8,5));
```

that looks

[image]

I want to replace 0,1 ,..., 5 into 0.1, ..., 0.6 (it's my column S), so I set x.

```
df_to_plot.plot.bar(y=['P(S)', 'P(S|X)'],
                    x='S',
                    alpha=0.7,
                    color=['red', 'green'],
                    figsize=(8,5));
```

which result is below.
[image]

I don't have any idea how to correct it. I used to use parameters [use_index, xticks](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) but they couldn't work.

Could you look at it and advise?
Thank you!

**Edit**
Thanks to @Mr.T I made a few changes.

```
ax = df_to_plot.plot.bar(y=['P(S)', 'P(S|X)'],
                         alpha=0.7,
                         color=['red', 'green'],
                         figsize=(8,5));
                         ax.set_xticklabels(df_to_plot['S'])
```

The chart looks fine now :)
[image]

Comment: Your initial problem is not reproducible outside kaggle (matplotlib 3.3.3, Python 3.8, pandas 1.1.4). As a workaround, you can redefine the xtick labels afterward with your column S: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280076/8881141

Comment: Thank you - I tried to use this, but it doesn't work. The images that show how it looks after modifications are below

Comment: This is not what the linked thread suggests. It says use `ax = df_to_plot.plot.bar(y=['P(S)', 'P(S|X)'], alpha=0.7,...` which plots it against the index, then `ax.set_xticklabels(df_to_plot["S"])` which substitutes the index labels. What is the outcome of this? Still weird behavior in any case.

Comment: Thank you! It works now as it should be

Answer (score 1):

I am writing an answer since I cannot write a comment due to the low reputation.
Given your code, it creates an expected output with matplotlib version 3.3.4.
[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQM9Q.png)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
    p_s = [0.05, 0.15, 0.20, 0.30, 0.20, 0.10]
    p_s_x = [0.06005163309361129, 0.4378503494734475,0.3489460783665687,0.1404287057633398,0.012362455732360653,0.00036077757067209113]
    
    df_to_plot = pd.DataFrame(data={"P(S)": p_s,
                                    "P(S|X)": p_s_x,
                                    "S": s})
    
    df_to_plot.plot.bar(y=['P(S)', 'P(S|X)'],
                    x='S',
                    alpha=0.7,
                    color=['red', 'green'],
                    figsize=(8,5))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I put my code once again to a new Kaggle notebook (I forgot to mention that I work in Kaggle notebook (as Jupyter equivalent)) and received what I got before. But it's nice to see that your result is fine!