# How to use xticks in DataFrame.plot as argument?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Week 1': [5000,5900,6500,3500,4000,5300,7900],
    'Week 2': [4000,3000,5000,5500,3000,4300,5900],
    'Week 3': [4000,5800,3500,2500,3000,5300,6000],
}) #Sales in INR
```

Instead of using

```
df.plot()
plt.xticks(df.index.tolist(), 
['Monday','Tuesday','Wednusday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'])
```

How to use `xticks` as a parameter in the `df.plot()`.
I tried:

```
df.plot(xticks=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednusday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'])
```

but got error:

```
ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 
'Wednusday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible – see [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280076/7117003).

Comment: check https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html
it has a parameter `xticks`

Comment: Sorry – what I meant was, that it doesn't seem to be possible to set the xtick **labels** in the function call (the xticks you obviously can set).  Does the code in my answer help you achieve what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Set the ticks and the labels like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Week 1': [5000,5900,6500,3500,4000,5300,7900],
    'Week 2': [4000,3000,5000,5500,3000,4300,5900],
    'Week 3': [4000,5800,3500,2500,3000,5300,6000],
})

df.plot()
plt.xticks(ticks=df.index, 
           labels=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I know it can be done like this.
But I wanted to know whether it can done by the method specified in the question